# Laravel 5.1 Send mail to all users in foreach [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException] Client error: 400

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, guzzle

I'm trying to send an email to all the users in the database, but I'm getting the following error: [GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException] Client error: 400.

Here's my code:

```
$users = App\User::all();

foreach($users as $user) {
    $code = new App\Code();
    $code->code = str_random(10);
    $code->save();

    Mail::send('emails.code', ['code' => $code], function($message) use ($user)
    {
         $message->to($user->email)->from('foo.bar@gmail.com', 'Foo Bar')->subject('New code, new chances!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you proven that `$user->email` is, in-fact, valid?

Comment: Yes, all emails are valid.

Answer (score 0):

[GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException] Client error: 400
is for URL not found
Check for **host** url in config/mail.php, host url might be wrong

Comment: If I replace `$user->email` to my own email, it works fine. So I think the host url is okay (smtp.mailgun.org)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have got it working but I had the exact same problem today and I had no idea what went wrong as I did the exact same implementation just in my previous Laravel project with mailgun. Then I found the issue in the configuration.

So, here is the glitch..I don't know in which version it was changed, but in config/services.php the mailgun config is now like this,

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

where it was like this before as far as I can remember,

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAIL_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAIL_SECRET'),
],
```

so in my .env file, I was only referencing MAIL_DOMAIN and MAIL_SECRET environment variables but I just realised in the services.php file, it's actually referencing different environment variables - MAILGUN_DOMAIN and MAILGUN_SECRET.

So I've just added these environment variables, cleared the config cache and it is working perfectly now.

(I am working with Laravel 5.1.23 version BTW)

Hope this helps. Thanks.